# Not able to handle multiple login pages in the main and sub-application using MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Problem Statement:**

I'm having two applications built using MVC razor namely:

1. Main Application
2. Sub Application

Both the applications are working fine independently.Now i'm trying to integrate sub application in the main application.Both the applications is having separate login pages with respect to different table.

***Problem what i'm facing after integrating sub application in the main application:***

I will login into main application with the credentials.Now from Home page of main application i will login to the sub application with different credentials,which logs in properly.Only problem what i'm facing after logging into sub application is that username for both main application and sub application takes the username of sub application.

How to avoid this??? What i'm doing wrong???

**Please refer the images for more understanding :**

**Main Application Login :** *I'm able to login with the credentials.*

[image: Main App Login]

**Main Application Home :** *I'm able to display logged in username on the main application home page as Vishal1 using **User.Identity.Name property.***

[image: Main App Home Page]

**Sub Application Login:** I'm able to login with the credentials for sub application.
[image: Sub App Login]

**Sub Application Home :** I'm able to display logged in username on the sub application home page as Vishal2 using **User.Identity.Name**,but **Username in the main application home page is changing as Vishal2,which is suppose to be Vishal1**.Both the usernames should display as it is shown in the final image.

[image: Sub App Home Page]